# How to format / parse a Date in Scala and ScalaJS

Tags: scala, date, scala.js

I want to use Dates in shared code (JVM and JS).

So I need the functionality to parse a Date from a Text and to format a Text from a Date.

I found that *ScalaJS* supports `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Formatter`, but with this there is no way to parse a Text to a Date.

Is it possible to have this in shared code? Or what is the best practice to handle dates in this scenario.

Comment: You would be very badly off with `java.util.Date` since it’s a poorly designed and long outdated class that you would not want to work with. Fortunately I read that scala.js also supports an implementation of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). See [cquiroz /
scala-java-time on GitHub](https://github.com/cquiroz/scala-java-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `java.time` APIs through https://github.com/cquiroz/scala-java-time to manipulate date/time in a cross-platform way.

For parsing, use the `java.text` APIs through https://github.com/cquiroz/scala-java-locales.

Comment: Assuming that scala-java-time includes `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and other classes in that package,definitely do not resort to `java.text.DateFormat` or `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` for parsing. Those classes are **soooo** troublesome.